# Loading web fragment when running embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

In a test environment I'm trying to run an embedded jetty with some application. the application depends on `some-dependency` which specifies a `web-fragemnt.xml` in it's `META-INF` folder. I'm trying to load the fragment like this:

```java
public static void someMain(...) {
    server = new Server(port);
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    addFragmentIfExists(context);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    context.setResourceBase(pathToWebapp);
    server.setHandler(context);
}

private void addFragmentIfExists(final WebAppContext context) {
    final Optional<URL> url = Stream.of(((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs())
            .filter(u -> u.toString().contains("some-dependency")).findFirst();
    url.ifPresent(u -> {
        try {
            context.getMetaData().addFragment(newResource(u),
                    newResource(new File(u.getPath(), "META-INF/web-fragment.xml")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

when debugging I can see the fragment is loaded under `server.handler.metadata.webFragments{Roots,NameMap,ResourceMap}` but under `server.handler.{filters,servlets}` I don't see the filter and servlet declared in that fragment
What am I doing wrong?
Also, is there a less hacky way to load the fragment? I also have a spring web-fragment in the classpath so if I just try to load from classpath it loads the spring one

Answer (score 0):

Put the web-fragment jar in your `pathToWebapp + "/WEB-INF/lib/"` directory, and set the configurations to use Web Fragments.

eg:

```java
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
            .setServerDefault(server);
    classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
    classlist.addBefore(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    // ... etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, I'm not sure why should the configuration classes order be changed, their all loaded anyway, are there new classes in here?
Also, this solution is not general enough since the jar is already in that directory when in war form but when running a test in the IDE the fragment is in a classes directory in a target folder of the dependency project

Comment: I'm using jetty: `8.1.5.v20120716` I don't have these configuration classes om my classpath